# Loading a UTF-8 page

Tags: node.js, utf-8

I am trying to figure out what is the correct way to load a UTF-8 web page.
Below are my failed attempts so far.

I should also mention that:

- I am running this on Windows.
- I am using Sublime text console for output but also tried writing to file.
- Based on some other SO questions, I tried using the `iconv` module, but also failed (+ I suspect that there should be a solution without it).

#### Code:

```
var request = require("request");
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");

var url = "http://www.globes.co.il/portal/quotes/unlinked-fixed-rate-government-bonds";

// Attempt 1: Ask 'request' for utf8
request({url:url, encoding:'utf8'}, function(error, response, html) {
    console.log(html);
});

// Attempt 2: Ask 'request' for null
request({url:url, encoding:null}, function(error, response, html) {
    console.log(html.toString('utf8'));
});

// Attempt 3: Avoid using 'request'
var options = {
    host: 'www.globes.co.il',
    path: '/portal/quotes/unlinked-fixed-rate-government-bonds'
};

http.get(options, function(res) {
    res.on("data", function(chunk) {
        console.log(chunk.toString('utf8'));
    });
});
```

#### Side by side: actual vs. expected:

[image: Side by side actual vs expected]

Comment: In what ways are they failing?

Comment: It should also be noted that while the HTML has set a charset of utf8 via a meta tag, the HTTP response is specifying windows-1255 as the character set for the content. Did you try using the `iconv` or `iconv-lite` module with attempt #2 to convert from windows-1255 to utf8?

Comment: This is how they are failing: Instead of getting the proper UTF8 characters, I am seeing squares with a question mark. Just for comparison, when I did "view source" in Chrome, copied the code, pasted in a file and `fs.readFile`ed it, I saw the correct encoding. I will try iconv from windows-1255, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that despite the HTML having a reported charset of utf8, the HTTP response says the content charset is windows-1255.

Using `iconv-lite` to convert from the binary response to utf8 works (tested on Linux):

```
var request = require('request'),
    iconv = require('iconv-lite');

var url = 'http://www.globes.co.il/portal/quotes/unlinked-fixed-rate-government-bonds';

request({url:url, encoding:null}, function(error, response, html) {
  html = iconv.decode(html, 'win1255');
  console.log(html);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try your code on Windows. But do you mind explaining? I mean, who is the blame in this problem? Node's http? The request module? The site owner? - to clarify, I am trying to develop something generic, so trying to understand if I should always apply this, or not.

Comment: Well, node core only supports a few charsets. For anything else you'll need to use `iconv`/`iconv-lite`. You can check for an explicit charset by looking at `response.headers['content-type']`. The problem is though that (at least in `iconv-lite`) the charset names do not always match the charset names given in `Content-Type` (e.g. `win1255` vs `windows-1255`), so you may need to create your own mapping and/or send a pull request to `iconv-lite` to add these aliases.

Comment: I simply ended up adding a parameter to the function to decide from the outside if I run the iconv command. Thanks, helped a lot.